# Помогите разобраться с lambda python

Tags: python

Значит есть такой массив данных и нужно: 'Определите количество пар элементов, из которых оба числа нечётные, а также максимальную сумму элементов таких пар'. Решая не выпендриваясь, то есть так:

```
arr = []
data = [8, 10, 3, 19, 20]

for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    if data[i] % 2 != 0 and data[i + 1] % 2 != 0:
        arr.append(data[i] + data[i + 1])
print(len(arr), max(arr))
```

Ответ 1, 22 и он верный. Но я решил поэкспериментировать и решить по другому, то есть так:

```
arr = []
data = [8, 10, 3, 19, 20]

for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    if all(lambda x: x % 2 != 0 for x in [data[i], data[i + 1]]):
        arr.append(data[i] + data[i + 1])
print(len(arr), max(arr))
```

Ответ 4, 39 - неверный. Он почему-то игнорирует мою функцию и добавляет все. Однако если вынести функцию, то есть так:

```
def f(x):
    return True if x % 2 != 0 else False


arr = []
data = [8, 10, 3, 19, 20]

for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    if all(f(x) for x in [data[i], data[i + 1]]):
        arr.append(data[i] + data[i + 1])
print(len(arr), max(arr))
```

Ответ 1, 22 и все хорошо. Помогите разобраться, что не так я делаю с lambda

Comment: В первую очередь "не так" - вы ненужно усложняете. lambda должна упрощать понимание, а не усложнять. all () не несёт смысла, кстати, можно убрать.

Comment: @Сергей Да я понимаю, что это излишество, но я хочу понять, почему это излишество работает неверно

Comment: @Сергей print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, [1, 3, 2, 5, 20, 21]))) тут тоже lambda x, то все нечетные числа пропадут

Comment: Никита, я не понял комментарий про "пропадут". То есть, да, они пропадут, но как это относится к обсуждаемой теме:-)? Но сам вопрос исходный интересным получился, спасибо:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` - это **ссылка на функцию**. Вы проверяете тут через `all` не **значение выполненной функции**, а просто что у вас там **что-то не пустое**. Ну, `lambda` - это что-то не пустое, да, поэтому оно всегда `True`. Для того, чтобы всё отработало правильно, вам эту лямбду надо **выполнить как функцию, передав ей аргументы**. Например, так:

```py
if all(map(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, [data[i], data[i + 1]])):
```

Или так:

```py
if all((lambda x: x % 2 != 0)(x) for x in [data[i], data[i + 1]]):
```

Имейте в виду, что `x` как аргумент `lambda` не имеет никакого отношения к переменной цикла `x`, это внутренняя переменная самой `lambda`, там можно любую другую букву написать. Собственно, ещё и поэтому `lambda` ничего не знает об итерациях цикла и переменной цикла, пока ей эту переменную явно не передадут как аргумент.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda тут не к месту. Она должна быть краткой формой заменяемой функции (эквивалентна ей). Она же возвращает значение х в вашем случае (lambda x), а не True или False, как эквивалентная функция.
Х же всегда True у вас, согласно правилам языка.